# Gridview ASP.NET is not shown when loading webpage

Tags: asp.net, gridview, objectdatasource

well I'm so new to ASP.NET I've been working on this project for about two weeks now, but I can't get a GridView with an objectdatasource to show when webpage loads, I can see all columns in design time.
The method returns a List and in design time I can see all columns with the right column name but when loading the service and the webpage afterwards nothing shows up. Any help will be appreciated. Regards to all readers.
The method receives a string value I've set a default to 'q'.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Contraseña" HeaderText="Contraseña" 
                SortExpression="Contraseña" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Id_User" HeaderText="Id_User" 
                SortExpression="Id_User" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Nombre" HeaderText="Nombre" 
                SortExpression="Nombre" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Tipo" HeaderText="Tipo" SortExpression="Tipo" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Usuario" HeaderText="Usuario" 
                SortExpression="Usuario" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Please provide both the HTML mark up and the code you use to get your data. The first thing coming to mind is that you didn't bind your data.

Comment: thanks AntLaC I just added the code, I got a question, do I have to bind my data manually or something like that?

Comment: How are you populating the datasource? Please also include the markup for the datasource and any relivent code to that. If you are populating your datasource in code, then you will have to manually bind your grid. The reason you see the columns in design time is because you have them explicitly defined.

Comment: Thank you @AntLaC but that code came out automatically when I set the ObjectDataSource I did not write the columns manually.

Comment: That's fine, but we still need to see the code for the data source. Try manually binding the grid.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
  EmptyDataText="DOH! No Data!" 
  ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True"
```

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine. You don't actually need to call databind() with Data Source Control, instead perhaps you need to check the return value in SelectMethod of objectdatasource.

Comment: it returns a List<Usuarios> but why while designing I can see the whole table with the right columns I mean, with the database columns and when loading my webpage it dissapears. Thanks Hatsuki.